# Writing to storage string vs bytes for token parameters

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design

I'm wondering why string is used to define token parameters such as name, and symbol? Why can't I use any form of bytes such as `bytes8` etc.

I understand that it's a public parameter and non-devs will be able to check up the name etc in string encoded readable format but I want to use bytes where ever possible to decrease gas-costs.

How would I go about describing following line in bytes format? `string constant public name = "Nowsy Token"`

Comment: How would I go about describing following line in bytes format?
string constant public name = "Nowsy Token"

Comment: `bytes11 constant public name = "Nowsy Token";`

Comment: You can edit the question if the duplicate marked question doesn't answer your problem :)

Comment: If you add the answer ,then i can upvote it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why can't I use any form of bytes such as bytes8 etc

yes, you can use the [fixed-size byte array](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#fixed-size-byte-arrays) , if you are sure that the length of it would not be longer than that. Say `byte8`, it has to be less than 8 characters.

From the docs,

> As a rule of thumb, use bytes for arbitrary-length raw byte data and
>   string for arbitrary-length string (UTF-8) data. If you can limit the
>   length to a certain number of bytes, always use one of bytes1 to
>   bytes32 because they are much cheaper.

And for you requirement,

> How would I go about describing following line in bytes format? string
>   constant public name = "Nowsy Token"

you can use `bytes11 constant public name = "Nowsy Token";` since it's constant and you know the size of it's 11.

Comment: But i would have to convert "Nowsy Token" to bytes yes? otherwise it would implicitely not understand the format

Comment: now it's in a fixed-size byte array type of byte11, you can just use it

Comment: @NowsyMe Notice that if you intend to make your token ERC20 compliant you shouldn't change the name data type.